# when do i use wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Well I have a lot of confusions about wordpress. And I unfortunately could not find a satisfactory answer to my questions. So expecting a detailed answer.

To what extent we can customize a wordpress website?
for what kind of projects we should use wordpress.
Can we create a database oriented website in wordpress?

For example I want to create a website that will probably have Home | Products| Contact Us pages. And there will be two tables categories table and actual products table (where each product belongs to a category). Admin will like to add/modify categories and products later.

Should I use wordpress or simple php/CodeIgniter for developing this kind of project?

Comment: This belongs on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This post could be of some help....

[Innovative uses of WordPress](http://maisonbisson.com/blog/post/tag/innovative-uses-of-wordpress/)